# Trying to create a regexp_substr expression to grab url out of apex_util.prepare_url return value

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm currently trying to grab the apex page url out of this apex_util.prepare_url return value:

javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=97137:10:117255676898495:::RP:P10_ANSWER_ID:229&p_dialog_cs=xlNjdk3Cf7inJRB81uDxydfE7I-lHmDmlqYP96g_SdtbmGT6T5-1SVLEK-MSJ7H4JfeO6WZvAd3gQKLvQr6kNQ',{title:'Link Documents',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:true,dialog:null},'t-Dialog-page--standard '+'',this);

What I need is ''f?p=97137:10:117255676898495:::RP:P10_ANSWER_ID:229'

What I've tried was this:

regexp_substr(apex_util.prepare_url( p_url ), 'f?p=[^'']*');

For some reason this is returning nothing at all. I'm still very new to working with Apex and programming in general, and extremely green when it comes to creating regex expressions. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the purpose of this 'need'?

Comment: If you dont need the checksum, you could instead just build the URL using `:APP_ID`, `:APP_SESSION` and your items/values. Also I too really don't understand the purpose of this.